# Issue with regsub on a string with square brackets with variables in tcl

Tags: regex, tcl

I am unable to have the current pattern for regex substitution on a string that has square brackets with variable defined as the index.

I have tried the following as decribed in the code

```
set p "not r\[0\]"
set bit 0
set value 1
set x [regsub -all {r\[$bit\]} $p $value]
```

Expected result is x = "not 1"
Output = 0

Comment: In this case, `string map [list "r\\\[$bit\\\]" $value] $p` would do just as well. It works like a simplified `regsub -all`, only changing literal strings to other literal strings. And it can map several things at once, which is _very_ useful…

Comment: Thanks for the input! That worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why there is no substitution is because you the expression is trying to match the literal string `r[`, then `$` which means 'end of line', then the literal string `bit]`. To allow substitution of variables, you will have to use double quotes, but that means you will have to be more careful with the escaping since with that, you now have to double escape (one to escape the backslash, another to escape the square parens):

```
set p "not r\[0\]"
set bit 0
set value 1
set x [regsub -all "r\\\[$bit\\\]" $p $value]
```

The above gives you `not 1`.

Some not so common solution I guess would be to try using [`format`](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/format.htm) to perform the substitution:

```
set x [regsub -all [format {r\[%s\]} $bit] $p $value]
```

Or the [string literal metacharacter](http://tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/re_syntax.htm#M82) (`***=`) for Tcl with double quotes:

```
set x [regsub -all "***=r\[$bit\]" $p $value]
```